# Firefox always try to open zip files with Evince

Tags: firefox, gnome-shell

I dont have any clue why Firefox try to open files with Evince, my desktop is gnome shell when I run

```
xdg-mime query default application/zip
```

I got `org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop` and Files (aka Nautilus) by default uses the FileRoller

Answer (score 0):

In your Firefox profile, *[handlers.json](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/change-firefox-behavior-when-open-file)* determines how MIME types are handled. You can delete that file and Firefox will recreate it, or it can be edited to specify an application.
[image]